# How to access root_path with url param (in host app, from rails engine)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

#### Setup

engine's `routes.rb`:

```rb
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  get '/:guid', :to => 'foo_bar#index'
end
```

mounted in host app via `mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => '/some_route'`

#### Issue

Somewhere in a helper in the host app:

```rb
generated_link = my_engine.root_path(some_guid_i_got)
```

results in

```
undefined method `root_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00007ff443d405a0>
```

I tried adding `include MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers`, but that broke a bunch of other routes that aren't even related to the engine.
Engine is working other than this url-helper, but I don't want to hard-code the url in.

What's the proper way of generating the url for `/some_route/a-guid-here`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The error is letting you know what's wrong. `undefined method root_path` is letting you know that it can't find the `root_path` defined and that is a required path to have in your routes file.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you mean `/` is a required route? Even for an engine? And how do I generate a route for `/:guid`?